output deliver %s instead of the string content
I have a new strange behavior with some tools, as with Python pip, reinstalling it didn't solve the problem. In /var/log/syslog, there are also no special error messages.
A normal working pip delivers this :
pip install wheel==10.10.10
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel==10.10.10 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 0.9.3, 0.9.4, 0.9.5, 0.9.6, 0.9.7, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.10.3, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.14.0, 0.15.0, 0.16.0, 0.17.0, 0.18.0, 0.19.0, 0.21.0, 0.22.0, 0.23.0, 0.24.0, 0.25.0, 0.26.0, 0.27.0, 0.28.0, 0.29.0, 0.30.0a0, 0.30.0, 0.31.0, 0.31.1, 0.32.0, 0.32.1, 0.32.2, 0.32.3, 0.33.0, 0.33.1, 0.33.4, 0.33.5, 0.33.6, 0.34.0, 0.34.1, 0.34.2, 0.35.0, 0.35.1, 0.36.0, 0.36.1, 0.36.2, 0.37.0, 0.37.1, 0.38.0, 0.38.1, 0.38.2, 0.38.3, 0.38.4, 0.40.0, 0.41.0, 0.41.1, 0.41.2, 0.41.3, 0.42.0, 0.43.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel==10.10.10
tarik@tata-nx1:~$

but newly, I get this :
tarik@tata-linux1:~/Downloads$ pip install wheel==10.10.10
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/, https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/pypi/simple
ERROR: Ignored the following yanked versions: %s       <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement %s (from versions: %s)<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel==10.10.10

The output delivers %s instead of the string content. I have this problem also in VLLM, all logging is coming with %s
Does somebody know how to solve the problem?
tarik@tata-linux1:~$ uname -a
Linux tata-linux1 6.5.0-44-generic #44~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Jun 18 14:36:16 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
tarik@tata-linux1:~$ python
Python 3.10.12 (main, Mar 22 2024, 16:50:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux

tarik@tata-linux1:~/AI-WS/vllm$ python -m pip debug  install yarl

WARNING: This command is only meant for debugging. Do not use this with automation for parsing and getting these details, since the output and options of this command may change without notice.
%s: %s
%s: %s
%s: %s
%s: %s
%s: %s
%s: %s
%s: %s
sys.implementation:
%s: %s
%s: %s
%s: %s
%s: %s
%s: %s
%s: %s
vendored library versions:
%s==%s%s
%s==%s%s
%s==%s%s
%s==%s%s
%s==%s%s
%s==%s%s
%s==%s%s
=================================
pip and vllm are using the logging package. by both they use it like this : logger.info("Successfully uninstalled %s", dist_name_version)
logger.info("Successfully uninstalled %s", dist_name_version)
output :   Successfully uninstalled %s
logger.info("Successfully uninstalled %s" %(dist_name_version))
output : Successfully uninstalled yarl-1.9.4
so what is the reason that the first common syntax doesnot more work i dont know
after editing the pip file and replacing all logger syntax, the pip output is again normal.

pip is a link to pip3 on my both computer
I have just finished to modify the vllm logger syntax,
the vllm before correction :

and the result after correction no %s any more:

I have this problem on my both linux computer, perhaps they got update at nearly sametime, have same leveland packages

Looks like it's a bug in pip, right? Do you see this issue in anything other than pip? Does it also happen on non-python tools? Does it happen with your own scripts? If you run python -c 'print("%s" % "hello")', do you get %s or hello?

python -c 'print("%s" % "hello")'
hello
print run well

but if i use  this  : python -m vllm.entrypoints.openai.api_server      --model THUDM/codegeex4-all-9b      --trust_remote_code --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8080 --uvicorn-log-level debug --api-key gxxxjBCYA --max_model_len 65000 --dtype float16  --device cpu
The value of pi is approximately 3.142.
INFO 07-27 06:07:13 api_server.py:54] vLLM API server version %5.3f.<<<<
it feels like "%" has lost its special functionality,

vllm and pip use same  system to display messages:     import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(name)
logger.debug(
'No VCS found for editable requirement "%s"',
display,
)
